# JUnit 5 пропускать кейсы до их начала

Tags: java, junit

Есть ли возможность в JUnit 5 выполнить проверку кейса в списке, перед выполнением. Т.е. если он присутствует в списке - то запускать, в примере ниже дожен запуститься только firstCase

```
    List<String> checkList = new ArrayList<>() {{
        add("firstCase");
    }};

    @BeforeEach
    void checkInList(TestInfo testInfo) {
        String methodName = testInfo.getTestMethod().orElseThrow().getName();
        if (checkList.contains(methodName)) {
            startCase!
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void firstCase() {
        System.out.println("tra ta ta");
    }

    @Test
    public void secondCase() {
        System.out.println("tra ta ta 2");
    }
```

Comment: Используйте расширение - ExecutionCondition
https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.3/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/ExecutionCondition.html

Comment: А обычная аннотация `@Disabled` не подойдёт?  Можете посмотреть также [Baeldung: JUnit 5 Conditional Test Execution (англ.)](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-conditional-test-execution), есть аннотации для отключения тестов в зависимости от операционной системы, системных свойств (system properties), переменных окружения (env variables) и т.д.

Comment: нет, приходится вручную пролистывать много кейсов и снимать аннотацию,я хочу просто комментить кейс в списке и чтобы он не вызывался

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло ExecutionCondition, создал класс RunMethodCondition, зарегистрировал при помощи аннотации @ExtendWith(RunMethodCondition.class), в классе переопределил метод evaluateExecutionCondition в котором проверял наличие кейса в списке

```
public class RunMethodCondition implements ExecutionCondition {
        private final ListCases listCases = new ListCases();

        @Override
        public ConditionEvaluationResult evaluateExecutionCondition(ExtensionContext context){
            final Method testedMethod = context.getTestMethod().get();
            if (listCases.listKeyCases.contains(testedMethod.getName())) {
                return ConditionEvaluationResult.enabled("enabled");
            }
            return ConditionEvaluationResult.disabled("disabled");
        }
    }
```

```
@Test
        @ExtendWith(RunMethodCondition.class)
        public void secondCase() {
            System.out.println("secondCase");
        }

        @Test
        @ExtendWith(RunMethodCondition.class)
        public void secondCase2() {
            System.out.println("secondCase2");
        }
```